# XAML Image Brush, scale long short image to vertical and then crop left

Tags: xaml

How would I accomplish the following in XAML.

I am using a grid and when I do uniform it will stretch to the widest dimension.  How do I get it to size rezise to the vertical and then crop the left side?

[image: Resize and crop example]

Here is the XAML I am starting with.

```
<Grid x:Name="FullWrapBgImageGrid" Width="1247" Height="864" >
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="FullWrapBackgroundImage" Stretch="Uniform"  AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Right"/>
            </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```